# Import statement is undefined. React-Native

Tags: react-native, redux, redux-thunk

I have built a very simple react-native redux app with redux-thunk. When i run my app, i run into the error 'actionTypes is undefined'.  [Error and the line where the error is](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2maSs.png).

The app isnt anything to big, just has one action creator file and one reducer file with another index file. Been stuck on this for a couple of day. Anyone that can help, itll be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Can you show the contents of `actionTypes.js`? Looks like it might not contain and `export`, or contain a circular `import`.

Comment: So i added default to "export default const  FETCH_DATA = 'FETCH_DATA;" and now i get a error that says "failed to load bundle"

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are storing all of your action related `const` variables in `actionTypes.js`.

When defining them, you need to export them from the file itself, in order to use them from within another file. I think the code you've provided is fine, but my guess is you are not exporting `FETCH_DATA` in this case. EG - in `actionTypes.js`

```
export const FETCH_DATA = "FETCH_DATA";
... 
... // other variables can be done the same way
```

and so on.

Comment: Whats up? I added the word default to my export statement in the actionTypes file, but now i get a 'Failed to bundle error"

Comment: woops, just export const, changed my answer

Answer (score 0):

Are you exporting from actionTypes.js? Every single type you define there would need to be exported separately.

But do not use the 'default' keyword like you do in your reducer. That's used in the case that you have one thing to export.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. It would be better if you checkout [How to Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) page for future endeavor at Stack overflow. -Thank you